# What is the use of word_is_countable() function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to php frameworks and am studying codeigniter. While going through the code of the helper functions, I found the word_is_countable($word) function in inflector_helper.php under helpers.

The function is given below.

```php
function word_is_countable($word)
    {
        return ! in_array(
            strtolower($word),
            array(
                'audio',
                'bison',
                'chassis',
                'compensation',
                'coreopsis',
                'data',
                'deer',
                'education',
                'emoji',
                'equipment',
                'fish',
                'furniture',
                'gold',
                'information',
                'knowledge',
                'love',
                'rain',
                'money',
                'moose',
                'nutrition',
                'offspring',
                'plankton',
                'pokemon',
                'police',
                'rice',
                'series',
                'sheep',
                'species',
                'swine',
                'traffic',
                'wheat'
            )
        );
    }
```

The function seems to be pretty straightforward and seems to just check for a few words. If it checks for so few words, then how can we expect it to be robust and fulfill the needs of a dynamic application which might need to search for any word in the dictionary.

As such, I wished to know the reason for including this function in the framework. I am sorry if this sounds like a novice question. Thanks.

Comment: From [the docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/inflector_helper.html#word_is_countable), "*Checks if the given word has a plural version.*"

Comment: I'd suggest you contact someone through the CI forums, https://forum.codeigniter.com/index.php

Comment: @Qirel I understand that it checks if the word has a plural version. I went through the documentation too. What I wanted to know is that why is the list of words so small?

Comment: @Vickel Thank you for the suggestion. I will put up a question there.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of that function, as the Documentation states, is

> Checks if the given word has a plural version. Example:
>
> word_is_countable('equipment'); // Returns FALSE

There just aren't a lot of nouns in English that cannot be plural. That's why the list is so small.

Comment: that list is far from complete, check those:  Baggage, Luggage, Evidence,  Homework, Housework, Music and for sure many more :)

Comment: I think @Vickel is right. There can be more words as shown in Google search results too.

Comment: @Vickel You are correct that it isn't all inclusive. I found a much larger list online. One thing I noticed about that larger list is it includes words that, despite the grammar experts opinions, are commonly used as plurals. In other words, it's arguable. This might be a case where hacking the core would not cause regression bugs and could be done with confidence.

Comment: Here is the [largest list of uncountable nouns](https://7esl.com/uncountable-nouns/#Uncountable_Nouns_List_A_Z) I could find.

Comment: An English teacher friend pointed out that many nouns can also be used as verbs and the verb version can accept an 's'. That might explain why the list is smaller than we think it should be. No easy way to know whether the word is being used as a noun or verb, so leave the word of the list. Maybe?